# How could I send data to an HTML file while loading that page with jQuery but without PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to do this for a university assignment. I can only use jQuery and JavaScript. My professor has given us an API for interacting with the database, so that means we have a directory containing a lot of `.php` scripts we can call from the jQuery and JavaScript.

Basically I have an `Accounts.html` page which will display user information based on the clicked  list item in another page called `Projects.html` which contains an `ul` with one `li` for each user.

I have everything ready to go up to this point, but I don't understand how I could possibly send data to a `.html` page then load it from a script within that page without making it a `.php` page (meaning I'd be able to use POST data).

I suppose I could possibly use GET data, but I'd much rather use POST.

Or *can* you use POST with `.html` pages?

Please share your thoughts as to which solution would be best.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like your professor wants you to make an AJAX call to the API? It will definitely be a `GET`. You would not be "sending data" to an HTML file, per se, you would be sending out a call to the API and then parsing the response in your HTML.

Comment: Why don't you try to learn and try first...You will find it very interesting and pretty easy... believe me :)

Comment: I didn't want to send data to the server, I wanted to send a username to the other file so I could call the `.php` API using that username. I've decided to send it as GET data from the `Projects.html` page then split the `window.location.href` and `.split()` that... I end up with the username, but it's really ugly, the user can see it, and it required what seemed to be unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still a bit vague...it would be better if I knew exactly what you were trying to do.  In terms of a general idea of how JavaScript can load other files...

You can load external HTML files into sections of your code with jQuery's load method:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Or you can more directly control the data using jquery's get method:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

and then subsequently processing the HTML data to get the data you need out of it.  E.g. you could use get to get the HTML data...then put that HTML data into jQuery and grab the UL tags out of it and do further processing on those:

```
$.get('some/file',function(result) {
    var $uls = $(result).find('ul');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I want to send a string to another `.html` file, namely a script (JavaScript script) which is linked to that `.html` file.